# Black screen while nvidia driver is installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have installed Kubuntu 18.04 LTS and I want to use NVIDIA driver from nvidia.com.

My graphics devices are:

```
$ lspci | grep "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c8d (rev a1)
```

I have installed their driver from multiuser session (without X), blacklisted nouveau through adding lines

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, the lines

```
rdblacklist=nouveau
```

into `/etc/default/grub`,
made

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# update-initramfs -u
# reboot
```

After reboot I obtain black screen, while from other tty a can run nvidia-smi which returns correct result:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Fri Apr 12 20:33:11 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.43       Driver Version: 418.43       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     49MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       840      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             8MiB |
|    0       880      G   /usr/bin/sddm-greeter                         38MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so driver looks installed properly.

My configuration file and logs are here: [xorg.conf](https://justpaste.it/5r7ts), [Xorg.0.log](https://justpaste.it/6hse8), [dmesg](https://justpaste.it/57a78), [journalctl](https://justpaste.it/4b4nx).

The `xorg.conf` file was taken from Linux Mint installed at the same laptop where graphics starts properly with `nvidia` driver installed from repositories. Usage of `xorg.conf` produced during installation of the driver gives the same black screen (apart from absence of loading modesetting in Xorg.0.log).

Is it possible to run graphics with the latest `nvidia` driver at my system?

---

## Update 1

Additional information about my system:

```
$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

$ ls /sys/firmware/efi
config_table efivars esrt fw_platform_size fw_vendor runtime runtime-map systab vars

# lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             45056  3
nvidia_modeset       1085440  6 nvidia_drm
nvidia              17592320  221 nvidia_modeset
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
drm_kms_helper        172032  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   458752  8 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

---

## Update 2

`dkms status` doesn't return anything:

```
$ dkms status
$
```

---

## Update 3

I have reinstalled the driver then installed `bbswitch-dkms`. But result of starting X is the same.

Here are [Xorg.0.log](https://justpaste.it/1n1w3) and results of previously shown commands where result has changed:

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm            798720  0
nvidia_drm             40960  3
nvidia_modeset       1085440  6 nvidia_drm
nvidia              17592320  222 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
drm_kms_helper        172032  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   458752  8 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915

$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.18.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 418.43, 4.18.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed
```

The xorg.conf is the same as previously.  The output of `mokutil`, `ls /sys/firmware/efi`, `lshw`, `nvidia-smi` is the same as earlier.

I have found one more relevant log: /var/log/gpu-manager.log. Here are these files for Kubuntu and Linux Mint (where driver from repository runs X successfully): [gpu-manager.log.Kubuntu](https://justpaste.it/6mien), [gpu-manager.log.Mint](https://justpaste.it/27vtk). From the second log it is seen that bbswitch is used also. This was the reason to install it at Kubuntu, but for now I don't know how to use it...

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` 3. `sudo lshw -c video`  4. `dkms status` and 5. `lsmod | grep nvidia`

Comment: The result of `dkms status` I'll be able to post just tomorrow, when I will have wired Internet to install `dkms`...

Answer (score 0):

I have cured this by installing `nvidia-prime`.

Now X start correctly,

```
$ glxinfo | head
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,

$ glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
65344 frames in 5.0 seconds = 13068.664 FPS
66224 frames in 5.0 seconds = 13244.633 FPS
66325 frames in 5.0 seconds = 13264.833 FPS
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 54 requests (54 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

$ nvidia-smi | head
Tue Apr 16 16:10:47 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.43       Driver Version: 418.43       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    176MiB /  4040MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

$ ls /sys/firmware/efi
config_table  efivars  esrt  fw_platform_size  fw_vendor  runtime  runtime-map  systab  vars

# lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.18.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 418.43, 4.18.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             40960  9
nvidia_modeset       1085440  19 nvidia_drm
nvidia              17592320  895 nvidia_modeset
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
drm_kms_helper        172032  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   458752  13 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

The corresponding logs: [Xorg.0.log](https://justpaste.it/7rdbs), [gpu-manager.log](https://justpaste.it/6htad). X is run with xorg.conf presented earlier:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "nvidia"
    Inactive       "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver     "modesetting"
    BusID      "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option     "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Device     "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    BusID      "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option     "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Device         "nvidia"
    Option     "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option     "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

I was not able to start X with xorg.conf produced during installation of the nvidia driver.

So, to summarize, I have installed `dkms`, installed manually the driver (answering 'Yes' the question 'Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS?...'), blacklisted nouveau, installed `bbswitch-dkms`, `nvidia-prime`, and changed xorg.conf to look like the one shown above. After these steps X started properly.